# How to change the border color of a image while onBeforeDrag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles, webix

I have an html img element with source attribute. How to change the image border color while drag or drop?

```
<image src='" + "#src#" + "' height='185' width='150' />
```

below is my **onBeforeDrag** event.

```
$$("imageList").attachEvent("onBeforeDrag", function (context, ev) {
    if (ev.target.currentSrc != null) {
        //var imagepath = ev.target.currentSrc;
        document.getElementsByTagName('img').css = "myborder";
        console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('img'));
    }
});
```

**css:**

```
 .myborder {
    background:#D652D9;
    padding:12px;
    border:1px solid #999; }
```

Comment: for those wondering, `onBeforeDrag` is a custom event of the **Webix UI Toolkit** and **DHX UI Toolkit**.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName()` returns an Object containing a collection of elements.  So `.css` is not a property of that object, it is also not a property of each of the objects within that collection. IT appears you want to assign a css class name to the element. You do that with `.classList.add()`.

To fix that part, I recommend you use `document.querySelectorAll()` because it returns a different type of collection called a NodeList. The reason this change is important is because it has a `forEach()` method. So you can do this:

`document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(i=>i.classList.add("myborder"));`

That bit of code will assign the css class name "myborder" to each image on the page.